# MYSQL sql to find id's in a table with count greater than x

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has the raw data. In order to check for unwanted extra data I am trying to determine what id's (tickerid is the column, earningsdata is the table) have more than 50 rows of data. It would have to loop through all the current ticker id's (from a different table, earningstickers) and select only those id's that have more than 50 rows of data. I can do a select * by id but I'm not sure how to iterate through all the id's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to group by each `tickerid`, which will give you access to aggregate information related to each `tickerid` such as `COUNT`/`SUM`/`AVG`/etc...

For your purposes, we must use `COUNT`.

Then the `HAVING` clause filters out the `tickerid`s that have 50 rows or less:

```
SELECT tickerid
FROM earningsdata
GROUP BY tickerid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
```

This will just give you a list of the `tickerid`s that have more than 50 rows, however if you want to display all rows and information of the `tickerid`s that are in this list, you can join the table against this list by incorporating the above query into:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM earningsdata a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tickerid
    FROM earningsdata
    GROUP BY tickerid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
) b ON a.tickerid = b.tickerid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tickerid 
FROM earningstickers 
WHERE tickerid 
IN 
    (SELECT tickerid
     FROM earningsdata
     GROUP BY tickerid
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
     )
```